# How to Unit test the the strings are not nil which is parsed from JSON and stored in local string

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, xctest

I am using AfNetworking and parsing JSON and storing the values in a NSArray. every thing works fine as usual. but now i want to know how can i do unit test and make sure the NSarrays are not nil

i tried below, but the results are always nil

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "Media.h"

@interface ModelUnitTest : XCTestCase
@property (nonatomic, strong) Media * media;
@end

@implementation ModelUnitTest

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
 self.media = [[PPMedia alloc]init
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
}

- (void)tearDown {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testModelObject:(id)file
{
    XCTAssertNotNil(self.media);
    XCTAssertTrue(self.media isKindOfClass:[Media class]]);
    XCTAssertNotNil(self.media.name);
    XCTAssertNotNil(self.media.sex);
    XCTAssertNotNil(self.media.description);
}
```

I guess because the dictionary which holds the fetched data from JSON is not in this test file its showing nil, how do i handle this? i have to run Afnetworking and pull the dictionary in this testing file too or do i have any alternative way to test it.

i am confused can any one help me.

Comment: Where in this code are you doing anything with a JSON file?

Comment: i do not write code how i fetch data from JSON using, do you want me to write aft the code how i fetch JSON using Afnetworking here

Comment: No, I want to know what you are expecting to happen in this test - you talk about a dictionary file and JSON and fetched data but all you do is instantiate an object and check its properties. Are you trying to use a local JSON file in your tests to check your parser code? What are you trying to test?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing of Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955213/unit-testing-of-object)

Comment: no i just want know how to test the arrays are not nil by unittesting

Comment: i mean arrays of media class which holds data fetched from json